# how to get a count of the number of objects save

Tags: swift

I created a contact list, saving in the core data the contacts. I can access the contact by name but would like to know how to get a number of how many contacts I have saved so far.

I thought the managed object context would be able to give the coin since this is what creates a space for every new contact added, but this is not the case or maybe I am using it wrong.

This is the code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    @IBOutlet weak var name: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var address: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var phone: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var status: UILabel!

    @IBAction func saveContact(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Contacts", in: managedObjectContext)
        let contact = Contacts(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: managedObjectContext)

        contact.name = name.text!
        contact.address = address.text!
        contact.phone = phone.text!
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
            name.text = ""
            address.text = ""
            phone.text = ""
            status.text = "Contact Saved"
        } catch let error {
            status.text = error.localizedDescription               
        }          
    }

    @IBAction func findContact(_ sender: UIButton) {           
        let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Contacts",
                                                           in: managedObjectContext)
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Contacts> = Contacts.fetchRequest()
        request.entity = entityDescription
        let pred = NSPredicate(format: "(name = %@)", name.text!)
        request.predicate = pred
        do {
            var results =
                try managedObjectContext.fetch(request as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)
            if results.count > 0 {
                let match = results[0] as! NSManagedObject
                name.text = match.value(forKey: "name") as? String
                address.text = match.value(forKey: "address") as? String
                phone.text = match.value(forKey: "phone") as? String
                status.text = "Matches found: \(results.count)"
            } else {
                status.text = "No Match"
            }
        } catch let error {
            status.text = error.localizedDescription
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the number of objects for an entity with

```
do {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Contacts> = Contacts.fetchRequest()
    let numberOfContacts = try managedObjectContext.count(for: request)
    print(numberOfContacts)
} catch { print(error) }
```

---

Side note: Your `findContact` method is very cumbersome. This is an improved version

```
@IBAction func findContact(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let request: NSFetchRequest<Contacts> = Contacts.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@", name.text!)
    do {
        let results = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
        if let match = results.first {
            name.text = match.name
            address.text = match.address
            phone.text = match.phone
            status.text = "Matches found: \(results.count)"
        } else {
            status.text = "No Match"
        }
    } catch {
        status.text = error.localizedDescription

    }
}
```